# Tilemap drawing not working Java

Tags: java, swing, graphics, tile

I am making a small program that just draws a tilemap on my JPanel, but when i run the program, it draws the map, but its draws it twice, and when i maximize the window everything disappears.

here is my code:

```
 package main;

  import javax.swing.*;

  import java.awt.*;
  import java.io.*;
  import java.util.*;

  public class Board extends JPanel{

    int width = 10;
   int height = 10;
    int size = 30;

   int x;
   int y;

   int[][] map = map1.map;
   ArrayList<Tile> tiles = new ArrayList<Tile>();

   public Board(){

    loadMap();

    Thread t = new Thread(){

        public void run(){

            while(1 != 0){
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                repaint();

            }

        }

    };

    t.start();

    }

   public void loadMap(){
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {

            int tex = map[i][j];
            Tile t = new Tile(x,y,tex);         
            tiles.add(t);

            x+= size;
        }
        y += size;
    }
    }

   public void drawMap(Graphics g){

   int index = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {

            Tile t = tiles.get(index);

            if(t.tex == 0)
                g.setColor(Color.gray);
            else if(t.tex == 1)
                g.setColor(Color.magenta);

            g.fillRect(x,y,size,size);

            index++;
            x += size;
        }
        x = 0;
        y += size;
    }

   }

   public void paint(Graphics g){

    drawMap(g);
   }








    public static void main(String[] args){

        JFrame j = new JFrame();
        j.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        j.setVisible(true);
        j.add(new Board());
        j.setSize(600,600);
        j.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    }



 }
```

My tile class and map class are self explanatory, the Tile class just holds a couple variables x,y, and the map just has an array[][] in it, and those don't seem to be the problem.

It prints the map out the way i wanted it to but then it has a clone below it and when i resize the window it everything just disappears. I don't know why it is doing this, and any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: To start with, you've broken the paint chain, meaning that the component is no longer updating itself correctly...

Comment: @MadProgrammer I apologize for being a noob, but can you elaborate please? I really can't figure this out

Answer (score 0):

Without having run the code:

## 1.

You are breaking the paint chain.  But not calling `super.paint` you are not allowing the component to prepare itself properly for painting.  Painting is a complex series of chained method calls which work together to produce the desired output, unless you're prepared to take over this work, you must always call `super.xxx` first.

It is typically recommended that you override `paintComponent` instead, for a vertiy of reasons, one of which you've just discovered...

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    drawMap(g);
}
```

See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details about how painting in Swing works...

## 2.

Your `drawMap` method is relying on instance fields to draw the grid, this means that each time the method is called, the values of `y` (in particular) are the same as they were when the method last exited...

No there's no real reason that they should be instance fields, they only have context within the `drawMap` method...

```
public void drawMap(Graphics g) {

    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    
    int index = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {

            Tile t = tiles.get(index);

            if (t.tex == 0) {
                g.setColor(Color.gray);
            } else if (t.tex == 1) {
                g.setColor(Color.magenta);
            }

            g.fillRect(x, y, size, size);

            index++;
            x += size;
        }
        x = 0;
        y += size;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you! I really noobed out there, but i changed y to zero after drawmap ends and added super.paint(g), now nothing is drawn at all on the screen.. do you know why this could be happening? @MadProgrammer EDIT: Figured it out, didnt reset x and y. -_- thanks for the help!